# Compass can't find any Sass files to compile when running grunt

Tags: sass, gruntjs, compass

I have made a grunt task to run compass as follows:

```
module.exports = {
      dev: {
          options: {
              sassDir: ['**/*.scss'],
              cssDir: 'stylesheets',
              noLineComments: false,
              outputStyle: 'compressed'
          }
      }
     }
```

My watch task is as follows:

```
module.exports = {
   jade: {
      files: 'app/views/**/*.jade',
      tasks: ['jade']
    },
     src: {
        files: '**/*.scss',
         tasks: ['compass:dev']
    },
           options: {
                livereload: true,
            },
}
```

However I get `Compass can't find any Sass files to compile.`

My folder structure is as follows:

```
scss/
stylesheets/
Gruntfile.js
grunt/
  aliases.yaml
  compass.js
  watch.js
```

Comment: Are you sure that is the correct format for sassDir?  If that's supposed to be for Compass, that's not what the value should look like.

Comment: do you have a **config.rb** file?

Comment: No is that needed? @AlvaroJoao  thanks

Comment: I thinl this https://gist.github.com/alvarojoao/de7f4b5bc4135bcc911f will help

Comment: Thanks but would I need to change anything in my code? Where soes the config.rb have to be placed? @AlvaroJoao

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can create a file called **config.rb** in the same leval as gruntfile.js**
[Reference](https://gist.github.com/alvarojoao/de7f4b5bc4135bcc911f)

then you can tell where the compass will look for the sass files:

```
css_dir = 'assets/stylesheets' #where find the css 
sass_dir = 'assets/sass' #where find sass files
images_dir = 'assets/images' #where find the images (if you want to use then in css as well)
```

You don't need to change the code.